# $|\operatorname{Gal(K/F)|} \le [K:F]$ where $K$ is a finite degree extension over $F$.

Tags: field-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $F$. Then we have to show that
$$
|\operatorname{Gal \ (K/F)}| \le [K:F]
$$
where $\operatorname{Gal \ (K/F)}:=$ Set of all automorphisms from $K$ to $K$ which fixes $F$.

---

How should I proceed to prove this result? Any hints will be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this site. There are several posts with a proof.

Comment: This is a very standard result and most textbooks on Galois Theory discuss this. In case of equality the extension $K/F$ is Galois.